# Mapping international firms in I/B/E/S to Compustat

Tags: data

Follow up to my [previous question on how to map I/B/E/S to Compustat](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39230/mapping-i-b-e-s-to-compustat-via-6-digit-cusip).

A big chunk of firms in both Compustat and I/B/E/S failed to map via CRSP for me. After some investigation, I noticed that they are all "international" firms. According to [this article](http://www.crsp.com/resources/data), CRSP does not include international data. Consequently, a merge of Compustat and IBES via CRSP will not work for international firms.

Hence, my question, is there any other way to map I/B/E/S to Compustat, that might work for international firms as well?